# How to separate based on a specific string

Tags: linux

In Linux, I want to separate a string using a specific string in a file and store the separated string in each column.

A specific string is / , and has it in common.

[image]

There are a lot of columns in 100,000 units.

What should I do?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do this in R, like your tag suggests:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(y) gsub("/", " ", y)))
```